# BTC Arbitrage Opportunity question

Tags: trading, buy-bitcoins, arbitrage

I have an bank account that allows me to exchange between currencies at no extra premium other than the exchange rate.

I am noticing large spreads between some of the BTC prices in various currencies.

For example

1 BTC USD is 9283
1 BTC GBP is 5382 (7338 USD)

I am seeing this correctly, does it make sense .....is this an arbitrage opportunity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Is this an arbitrage opportunity?

You also need to consider the exchange rate between the two currencies to determine if this truely is an arbitrage opportunity.

1 British Pound currently buys 1.39 US Dollars[<sup>1</sup>](https://www.google.com/search?q=exchange+rates) whereas the transfer via BTC using the figures you have quoted yeilds 1.724823486 times.

This is indeed an arbitrage opportuniy if you can buy BTC in British Pounds and sell them for more US Dollars, provided you have some British Pounds to buy them with initially (and allowing for any additional cost of buying them, and the transaction fees).

If you can instantly buy and instantly sell this is *possibly* (the disclaimer) a large opportunity.

rel:
[1](https://www.google.com/search?q=exchange+rates). According to [Big Internet Search Engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=exchange+rates).

Comment: Thanks.....Looks like this one is gone for now, but RMB arbitrage is back...